# vuejs set img src by using current route name

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

There is a file contains images.Every pictures'name is a route name. I want to change the img src attribute by current route name.But I can not get the full path,only can get the picture name.

```
<template>

<!-- footer -->
<div class="index-footer">
  <img v-bind:src = "$route.name" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { Carousel } from 'iview'
// export default {
//   components: { Carousel }
// }

export default {
 name: 'index',
 data () {
   return {
     index: '/static/img/footer/index.png',
     more: '/static/img/footer/index.png',
     product: '/static/img/footer/index.png',
     information: '/static/img/footer/index.png',
     news: '/static/img/footer/index.png',
     down: '/static/img/footer/index.png',
     enterprise: '/static/img/footer/enterprise.png',
     value3: 0,
     setting: {
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 4000,
      dots: 'inside',
      trigger: 'hover',
      arrow: 'hover'
     },
     scrolled: false
   }
 },
 components: {
   Carousel
 }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding the src at all. You need to use the binding directive to bind the src.

Like this

```
<img :src="index">
```

or this

```
<img v-bind:src="index">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this[this.$route.name]` or `this[$route.name]` as the binding text for `v-bind`.

[`v-bind` evals the text you pass in as javascript code (expression, to be more exact)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), with a bit extra trick of considering the variables in the expression to be members of the view-model (aka `this`).

The tricky part here is that we want `this[this.$route.name]`, which is confusing to translate to the v-bind text with the "I'll fill in the `this` for you" rule Vue provides. I tested a bit and found both `this[this.$route.name]` and `this[$route.name]` works. Not sure why they work, however. :/